# Android:How to change the GridView Images while clicking the imageview

Tags: android

I am developing a game in which i used 4*3 grid size using gridview.i initially loaded images for each imageView in gridView.i want to change the images while clicking the previous  image.

Comment: will u make it clear? which imageview u wanna click? is it the same image frm grid?

Comment: can u please modify the question to make it understandable ?

Answer (score 0):

Set a click listener on the Grid view object. Suppose g is the grid view object, then

g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```

Now in the method onItemClick, you can handle the click on the images and change image accordigly.
for more follow the link [onItemClick.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)